# Where are the tests for every Tensorflow GPU kernel?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to write my own op, and it would be useful to know where the tests for this live in the codebase. I know that tensorflow/core/kernels is where the kernel implementation lives. Are the *_test.cc files in this directory testing the GPU kernel implementation? I have looked through these files, and it seems like a lot of those tests are running on the CPU (I see `DEVICE_CPU` in most of the `CreateOpKernel` calls). Is there any other tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the specific gpu (cuda) test for tensorflow/core/kernels, look at the [BUILD](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD) file in the tensorflow/core/kernels directory and look for the stanzas starting with:

```
tf_cuda_cc_test
```

those define every cuda specific test.

To make it easier to run all cc test with cuda support an example [script/bazel](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/ci_build/linux/gpu/run_cc_core.sh) command is provided.

Comment: Are all the tests under tensorfow/core/kernels run on the gpu using that command?

Comment: That command has several parameters to limit the test run, but yes all small and medium cc gpu test under tensorflow/core/kernels is run. If you want to reduce the scope of the test you can replace the last line of the script with '//tensorflow/core/kernels/...'

Comment: what does ` -- --benchmarks=..` mean, and where is the `benchmarks`?

Comment: @skytree, I have never tried to run the benchmarks test myself so I'm unable to answer that. You may want to post a different question on that or ask in google's tensorflow-developers forum.